# How to remove last account from mail app?

Tags: pantheon-mail

How do you remove the last and only email account remaining in the Mail app? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but, the account is still there. Moreover the account cannot be removed via the Accounts pane *(Ctrl + M)* as the `-` is grayed out and not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Delete mail account folder in ~/.local/share/pantheon-mail/

Comment: Did some reading prior to posting the question. I actually tried that even before uninstalling the app itself, however it didn't work. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/eyAKY4y.png) of the contents of the ~/.local/share folder. Simultaneously, I have the mail app opened showing the inbox of the last account I'm unable to delete.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to get it fixed. I was able to delete the only email account in the mail app by removing the `pantheon-mail` package via the terminal using `sudo apt-get --remove pantheon-mail`. This change however, was not reflected in the elementary OS AppCenter, as the mail app was still showing up as installed. Upon clicking the **Uninstall** button I got an error. So I used `sudo apt-get -f install pantheon mail` to get the app installed back on the system, and fortunately this resulted in the app being in it's initial state *(having no email accounts)*.

So weird that they don't let you delete an email account if it's the only one. Does anyone know of a logical reason for that?

Comment: I do not know why it is like that but to avoid a lot of troubles by removing and installing packages it is more safe to do that by deleting the account folder in ~/.local/share/pantheon-mail/ folder, as it is suggested into the other answer. These folders containt a database file and attachments folders only for the account and if you remove them you cannot do any harm to the system but by removing packages using terminal - you can. Because mail is not just one package. Removing last account may be an issue if you are interested you can post one into https://github.com/elementary/mail/issues

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and didn't have any luck. That stubborn account was still there. I ended up adding another account and removing the problem account. Then, I found that Mail is still not displaying any messages, just the folders and unread counts.